# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} np-\log n = c$ then why $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(1-p)^{(n-1)} = e^{-c}$?

Tags: limits, random-graphs

If $p$ is a function of $n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} np-\log n = c$ for some constant $c$, then why does $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(1-p)^{(n-1)} = e^{-c}$ hold?

I see that we would have $\lim_{n \to \infty} ne^{-np} = e^{-c}$ in this case, but why the stated limit?

Comment: Do you know that $(1-x)^{1/x} \to 1/e$ for small $x$? And from the given limit you can deduce how $p$ scales in terms of $n$, which you can then plug into the second limit.

Comment: Doesn't $p(n) \to c/n + (\log n)/n \to 0$ as $n \to 0$ in this situation? I still don't quite see how to get there. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to be sure asymptotic estimates like $1-p \sim e^{-p}$ hold up to the abuses your limits demand of them is to write them as inequalities. In this case, a useful pair of two-sided inequalities (valid for all $x>1$) is:
$$\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{x} < \frac1e < \left(1-\frac1x\right)^{x-1}, \qquad \left(1 + \frac1x\right)^x < e < \left(1 + \frac1x\right)^{x+1}.$$
(We'll only need the first one, but I've included both for completeness. These are a few algebra steps removed from the most basic inequality: $e^x \ge x+1$.)

In this case, this tells us that $(1-p)^{1/p} < e^{-1} < (1-p)^{1/p-1}$, or $$1-p < e^{-p} < (1-p)^{1-p}.$$

Plugging this into the expression in our limit, we get
$$n (1-p)^n < n e^{-pn} < n (1-p)^{n-pn}$$
or
$$(1-p)^{pn} \cdot n e^{-pn} < n (1-p)^n < n e^{-pn}.$$
The correction factor of $(1-p)^{pn}$ is easily shown to approach $1$: for example, it is between $1 -p^2n$ and $1$ by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality). After that, we are done by the squeeze theorem.

Asymptotic calculations are the tedious part of studying random graphs, and I suggest that you just learn to replace $1-p$ by $e^{-p}$ whenever it occurs, as soon as it occurs; it will generally be valid by a computation similar to the one above, but you don't want to go through that justification every time.

Of course, you probably want to learn some of the tricks for doing the justification correctly, so you don't land in hot water like I did earlier.

Comment: Playing fast and loose with these asymptotics has definitely been the bottleneck for me. I keep coming across asymptotic claims such as this one with no justification that leave me scratching my head. Even now that I understand and can follow your reasoning, I have trouble seeing the original claim intuitively. One thing that is bothering me in your explanation: why is it that we can just take the limit of the part inside the square brackets, temporarily ignoring the power of $\log  n + c$, as well as the $n$ factor in front? How do we justifiy that step?

Comment: That's... a good point. I'll go revise my answer. Too many years of playing fast and loose with asymptotics!

Comment: @theQman - okay, meet the new proof, bearing no resemblance to the old proof. (The answer to "why is it that we can...?" is "we can't", although we don't get in trouble unless the inside part converges much more slowly than the outside part.)

Comment: I'm still confused. How do you conclude anything from $n(1-p)^n < ne^{-pn} < n(1-p)^{1-p}$? If you want to use the squeeze theorem, don't we need something of the form $A < n(1-p)^{n-1} < B$, where $A$ and $B$ both converge to $e^{-c}$?

Comment: You can rewrite the inequality as $n e^{-pn} (1-p)^{pn} < n(1-p)^n < ne^{-pn}$. Basically, if $A < B < A(1+\epsilon)$, and you known that $\epsilon \to 0$ and that $B$ converges, you know that $A$ converges to the same limit because $\frac{B}{1+\epsilon} < A < B$.